# ConstraintViolationException while delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

When I run GET Http method `localhost:8080/api/empl/drivers/id=1` then I get json:

```
{
    "pesel": "240028313144621540785598931",
    "firstName": "Janusz",
    "lastName": "Nosacz",
    "login": "user2",
    "email": "driver@example.com",
    "isActive": null,
    "userRole": "DRIVER",
    "active": null,
    "id": 1
}
```

It's OK, bu when I want to delete id with DELETE Http method: `localhost:8080/api/empl/drivers/id=1` then I get error: `"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"FKDPOR9OHOV2F3OPTWE7TWE49TT: DBO.VEHICLE FOREIGN KEY(DRIVER_ID) REFERENCES DBO.DRIVER(ID) (1)\"; SQL statement:\ndelete from driver where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",`

The same happens when I run:

```
Driver employee0 = new Driver("94112757255", "Janusz", "Nosacz");
employee0.setUser(user2);
driverRepo.save(employee0);
driverRepo.deleteById(1L);
```

I think this is because of Vehicle who is associated with driver of id = 1. The association is indirectional. (Driver haven't association with Vehicle).

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

// ...

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Driver driver;

// ...

}

// ...

Vehicle vehicle0 = new Vehicle("1FTEF27L2VND02190");
    vehicle0.setDriver(employee0);
    vehicleRepo.save(vehicle0);
```

And this is how I make a delete on Driver:

```
@Service
public class DriverServiceImpl implements DriverService {

    private final DriverRepo driverRepo;

// ...

    @Override
    public void deleteDriver(Long id) {
        driverRepo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Accodring to similary problems found on stackoverflow.com I tried to use cascade.ALL and orphonalremoval=true but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to solve it? I guess I must remove references to the Driver with id = 1 for the Vehicle but it is problematic...
 Here is the full code of the app: https://github.com/woblak/deliverp

Comment: Can you add `on delete cascade` or `on delete set null` to the database schema vehicle table?

Comment: The tables are created by hibernate, not my sql, so it's not so simple... Donno how to add it with jpa, i must seek...

Comment: How does the mapping of Driver look like?

Comment: Here is Driver: https://github.com/woblak/deliverp/blob/master/deliverp-core/src/main/java/com/woblak/deliverp/domain/Driver.java which extends Employee: https://github.com/woblak/deliverp/blob/master/deliverp-core/src/main/java/com/woblak/deliverp/domain/Employee.java and here is Vehicle: https://github.com/woblak/deliverp/blob/master/deliverp-core/src/main/java/com/woblak/deliverp/domain/Vehicle.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
class Driver {


@Id
Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="driver")
 Vehicle vehicle;

@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    vehicle.setDriver(null);
}

// getters and setters...


}

class Vehicle{

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    Driver driver;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The key was to make the association bidirectional and add method with `@PreRemove` annotation which runs before the object is deleted.

Comment: Please, reformat the code and add some description.